# Populating asp.net controls using javascript can't be read on server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-controls

I have an ASP.Net dropdown list that is populated using javascript like this:

Dropdown list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
       EnableViewState="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

The javascript code that populates the dropdown list with "text" is:

```
var select = document.getElementById('<%= Ddl.ClientID %>');
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.value = '1';
option.innerHTML = "Text";
select.appendChild(option);
```

It gets filled just fine in client side. I added a button that is supposed to run on server side. On the server side when I try to retrieve the ddl selected value; it gives an exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

I understand that the ASP.Net ddl control loses the content once form is sent to server?
How would I tackle this issue? I tried putting the value in hidden field and try using `Request.Form["HiddenField"].toString();` but it gives the same error. Any help?

Comment: Where are you trying to get the selected value? in the SelectedIndexChanged or your button click event? If you have AutoPostBack="true" you don't need a button to submit the selection.

Comment: Thank you for the respond; It is all cleared out after Ann L reply below. thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state, you can't populate a dropdown on the client side and have the server side know the `ListItem` objects are there.  That's because they don't get posted back to the server:  only the selected value does.

You might have better luck not even using a `DropDownList`.  Create the dropdown as an HTML `select` tag.  Be sure to set the `name` attribute (or it won't get picked up on postback).  Then use the `Request.Form` collection to access the selected value for the HTML `select`.

The only reason to use a `DropDownList` that I can think of, given what you've told us, would be if at some point you intend to bind it on the server side, from server-side data, or if you want to change its appearance based on a server-side calculation, but don't want to set up an Ajax call.  If you don't want to do either of these things, a `select` might serve you better.

Comment: Thnx I was planning to go for the Cascading DDls; and what you said makes more sense to not use server side controls if i do not have any server side binding...